# Ошибка "400 Bad RequestConnection" при получении веб-страницы через socket

Tags: java, http, сокет

Никак не получается получить веб-страницу через сокет. По заданию нужно получить веб-страницу сайта с доступом `http`. Код приведенный ниже работает например только для `server = "www.google.com"`, но если например попытаться получить веб-страницу `www.nytimes.com` уже выдает ошибку:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad RequestConnection: closeContent-Length: 0
```

Пока у меня получилось получить страницу только для `google.com`, с остальными возникает ошибка.

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket sock = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    String server = "www.nytimes.com";
    String path = "/";
    try {
        sock = new Socket(server, 80);
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
        pw = new PrintWriter(os);

        pw.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.0 \r\n");
        pw.println("\r\n");
        pw.println();
        pw.flush();

        StringBuffer sb =  new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sock.close();
    br.close();
    pw.close();
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Я находил в интернете всякие другие решения задачи, например используя `URL`. И да это отлично работает, но все таки задание использовать сокеты, `PrintWriter` и `BufferedReader`

Comment: `Bad Request` значит что в запросе чего-то не хватает или неправильные значения в заголовках (хотя у вас заголовков вообще нет). Посмотрите какие заголовки отправляет браузер

Comment: Можете подсказать, как правильно сформировать запрос? Или ссылку где написано об этом.

Comment: Правильно не руками делать, а использовать библиотеки для отправки http :) Еще можно посмотреть в инспекторе (F12) как браузеры такие запросы формируют: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0zGT.png

Comment: @gil9red да я понимаю, но я бы вопрос не задавал, а сделал бы через `URL`, если бы не требовалось сделать через `socket`. Попробовал добавить заголовок `Host` и `User-Agent`. Теперь ошибка `301 Moved PermanentlyServer`

Comment: Это редирект (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) смотрите в ответе заголовок Location, там новый адрес сервера

Comment: @gil9red почитал о `Location` и даже нашел похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219173/Ответ-301-moved-permanently-при-get-запросе-через-сокет-java), но как правильно запросы формировать так и не нашел.